# Java Deck of Cards suit and rank format

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, division, modulo

I have an integer array filled with values 0-51.

0-12
ranks 2-10JQKA of suit Spades

13-25
ranks 2-10JQKA of suit Hearts

26-38
ranks 2-10JQKA of suit Clubs

39-51
ranks 2-10JQKA of suit Diamonds

I need to find a way to use division in order to obtain the suit, and modulo for the rank.  NOTE: I would appreciate ideas, not answers, as I need some help getting started.

My current code consists of an if/switch statement structure.  However I'm looking for a way to implement the above requirements.

```
if(card <= 12) {
     switch(card) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
           System.out.println(card + " of Spades");
           break;
        case 9:
           System.out.println("Jack of Spades");
           break;
        case 10:
           System.out.println("Queen of Spades");
           break;
        case 11:
           System.out.println("King of Spades");
           break;
        case 12:
           System.out.println("Ace of Spades");
           break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Do just what you said, integer division by 13 for the the suit and modulo 13 for the rank.

Comment: How many cards are in each suit? What do you get when you divide the card number by that number?

Comment: You need to do the operation `rank = index % <something>` (where `rank == 0` means a two and so on). Taking the 3H, the index is 14, and the rank should be 1. What number do you need to use so that 14 % <something> == 1?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, to obtain the suit you can use div.
Lets say that `card` is in range [0-51].

```
suit = card div 13
```

To obtain the value within suite (`value` is in range [0-12]) you can use the formula

```
value = card mod 13
```

Comment: This looks like pascal or similar, the question is tagged with `java`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk The Answer works as pseudo-code. No need to do the student’s *entire* homework assignment for them.